# Using an Android device as a web server

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, web-server

How do I use my Android device as a web server by with an IP address and port? Just like a Wifi file transfer app in the Play Store?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve? Taken literally, this is impossible (the device is hardware, which cannot be transferred to software (yet)).

Comment: Check ths app in [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zbWFydGVyZHJvaWQud2lmaWZpbGV0cmFuc2ZlciJd) the app give ip and port which shows all files inside the sd card..

Comment: And? If that does what you want to do, your question has answered itself. I still don't get what you're asking for. The tags you provided help neither to get a clear idea (also a bit confusing). One more guess: maybe you don't mean "transfer", but "How to use an Android device as web server"?

Comment: Exactly.. I want my android device to work as a remote web server..

Comment: OK. Updated your tags accordingly to avoid confusion. Answer follows.

Answer (score 2):

Android itself does not provide such a facility (as to my knowledge). But there are a bunch of web servers available in the playstore. A German overview on AndroidPIT sums up some of them (grouped into suitable targets): [Webserver](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/438200/) (Google Translate's English variant: [Webserver](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F438200%2FUebersicht-Webserver)).

Some examples include static content webservers like e.g. [kWS - Android Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws) and [ServDroid.web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.servDroid.web), plain "HTTP file servers" like [File Expert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert) and [WiFi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer), more complex things even offering scripting support such as [PAW Server for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver), or all-in-one solutions like [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean enable web server on phone - there a lot of servers on market, but for file transfer (s)ftp is more usable.

[ES File explorer last versions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) support this, as example, or

[WiFi FileTransfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer), that less functional on device, but easier for use (freeware version has 4 Mb file size limit).